# MS Access won't link to tables in a Compiled Backend

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

I have a small  MS Access application that uses the Front end / Back end design.  I have decided to lock things down a little tighter, but my front end will not link to the tables if the back end is compiled (ACCDE) too.  The linking works fine when the BE is an ACCDB; the thing is, I really need to compile this BE because we don't have a file server to hide it away and there is a small amount of code in the BE just for Highly dangerous (to the data) Admin functions.

Comment: First time I've heard of accde backend but according to MS, it is possible. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095AB408-89C7-45B3-AAC2-58036E45FCF6. Why can't code be in frontend?

Comment: I tried with another split databases and there was no problem.  So it's something in the file itself.  Some corruption.  I've had weird Access corruptions before, but they always had to do with  a form suddenly not working.  There you just copy all the code from the form and paste it into notepad then delete all the form's code; save the form and then paste all the code back in and the problem disappears, but this seems to have some thing to do with compiling and I don't know where to look for the corruption.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing I am aware of that prevents you opening a front end, and linking to an accDB or accDE back end.

Of course if your back end has no code, so compiling down to an accDE not going to do anything. And it not going to improve security, since an accDE or accDB can freely be opened by Access.

Compiling a accDB to a accDE only strips out the VBA source code, and complies the application down to ONLY having the compiled VBA code. The result is that users cannot changes VBA code, or forms, or reports

However, since the back end ONLY has tables, then there is very little if any advantages to using an accDE in place of an accDB.

So creating an accDE for the back end will actually not result in anything more than giving you a different file extension. (Since no VBA code exists to be compiled).

When you launch the Access linked table manager, it freely allows you to choose an accDB or accDE for the source of those linked tables.

It is possible you done something else to that accDB (or now accDE), but what you done or changed cannot be determined by your post at this point in time.

All in all, to answer your question?

Access allows one to freely link to an accDB or accDE for the back end. There is no obvious reason as to why you are being prevented from doing this, but as a “general” choice in Access, linking to an accDE is allowed.

Comment: OP stated backend has VBA and that is the reason for ACCDE backend.

Comment: Ok, may have well missed the part about some code being in the back end. However, this should not change the basic issue of linking to a back end (the fact of code or even a startup macro etc. being in that back end does not effect nor matter as a normal course of action. So even me missing that little issue still should not change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as stated by Mr. Kallal, there should be no problem.  And it turns out there isn't, but in this case the Front end was doing something weird.  I though the table link manager was not running, because when I selected 'always prompt for new location' and I selected all tables, usually it would link all the tables at once, however in this instance it was only linking one table at a time and then re-prompting for a location.  When I realized it was successfully linking each table individually I repeated the process over and over until all tables were linked.  After that, the Front end went back to working as usual, linking all tables in one shot.  I'm not sure what was causing the problem; it may have been that I had somehow cross-linked to different versions of the BE and the built-in linkedTableManager process asked for a location for each individual table when it saw more than one original location.  IDK.    But Thanks for the ears guy... :)

Comment: If you select two linked tables, and they each have a different back end location (say a few linked to correct back end, and a few did not), then access will prompt you for every table. You can avoid the re-prompting if you always select tables from the same location. In your case, you had some linked to the same location, and some not. Access thus prompts for each table. So when re-linking, all tables must be from the same location, else access will prompt for each single table.